# Empty response when returning a user's unread FriendshipRequest DRF

Tags: python, json, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a DRF `ListAPIView` which should return a queryset of all a user's friends. To manage bi-directional friendship I use [django-friendship](https://github.com/revsys/django-friendship#getting-data-about-friendships).

Here is the `get_queryset` function of the `ListAPIView`:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return FriendshipRequest.objects.select_related('from_user', 'to_user').filter(
                to_user=self.request.user,
                viewed__isnull=True).all()
```

This returns a [FriendshipRequest](https://github.com/revsys/django-friendship/blob/master/friendship/models.py#L198) queryset. In the README.rst file it says to use `Friend.objects.unread_requests(user=request.user)` to get a list of all a user's unread `FriendshipRequest` model instances. However the `get_queryset` function should return a queryset not a list. Instead I copy the [source code](https://github.com/revsys/django-friendship/blob/master/friendship/models.py#L198) (line 198) to get a queryset of `FriendshipRequest` instances.

Here is the serializer currently in use:

```
class FriendRequestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='friendship_requests_sent')
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='friendship_requests_received')
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

I also want to serialize the `FriendshipRequest` `id`, but am not sure what code is needed to do this.

However, even though this user does have unseen friend requests, the response is the following JSON:

```
[
    {},
    {},
    {}
]
```

This user does have a total of 3 unread friend requests, however why are they completely empty?

If I try to change the serializer to a ModelSerializer like so:

```
class FriendRequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FriendshipRequest
        fields = ('id', 'from_user', 'to_user', 'created')
```

There is a status code 500, internal server error, because:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'values'
[01/Aug/2017 10:20:18] "GET /friendship/list-unseen-friend-requests/ HTTP/1.1" 500 16149
```

How do I make the `get_queryset` function to return a non null queryset of `FriendshipRequest` model instances to be returned as a List by the `ListAPIView`?

**THOUGHT**:

If the `ListAPIView` ultimately converts the queryset into a list and the code `Friend.objects.unread_requests(user=request.user)` returns a list of `FriendshipRequest` model instances, then why not use a `GenericAPIView`, override the get method and return the list as JSON directly eliminating the need to deal with querysets.

The only problem is that I wouldn't know how to convert a list of FriendshipRequest instances into a list in JSON. I think this is a better approach.

Does anyone know how to do this?